# Split subsets of a list to new variables

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames and I'm looking for a way to assign each subset (each data frame) to a new variable (with a dynamic name, corresponding to the name of the subset) that I could manipulate.

Is there a specific function for it?

Thank you

Comment: It is better to keep it in a `list` and not create variables in the global env

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this:

```
for(counter in 1:length(var_list)){
     assign(paste0('var_', counter), list[counter])
}
```

However as mentioned in the comments its not a good idea to pollute environment.

Comment: `length(list)` will return `1`